# Pentaho Data Integration: Add columns (fields) based in a another column

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using a Pentaho Data Integration and I want add columns for geographic coordinates to a location.

In the input table I have the column location (can be repeated), p.e: Luz Stadium (Lisbon), and for the output table I want to **add two columns based in the location**, the latitude and longitude columns.
I have this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GYm5.png)

**I plan to add the coordinates manually**, but I don't know how I do this.

P.e: If (location = Luz Stadium) -> Lat = 38.752920, Long = -9.184828

Like this:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRwHp.png)

I have already tried it with the Calculator but I couldn't.

How can I do this in PDI?

Answer (score 0):

@josecosta : You need to create a metadata table which has entries.

Location|Latitude|Longitude
Luz Stadium|38.752920|-9.184828
ABC|20.12934|1.234

Then you need to use database lookup component which will fetch these two columns based on source data, and hence it will add two columns in the row. Please let me know you need any other help